# How to filter by fields equal?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model:

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item')
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ritem = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='r_item')
```

And I want to find all where item=ritem. How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) object. This will compare the value of the two fields in the database.

```
from django.db.models import F

models = MyModel.objects.filter(item=F('ritem'))
```